# Moving away from DevC++ to command line compiling

Tags: c++, windows, compilation

I've inherited a large volume of C++ code for running & monitoring laboratory equipment.  Currently the deployment is managed by compiling all of the individual modules (each it's own program) using DevC++, manually moving all the .exe files to a Dropbox folder, and then running them on the host machine manually.

I'm trying to automate this process somewhat to make rolling out an implementation on a new machine simpler and making sure the most up to date binaries are what is running on any given machine quickly.  However, I don't know anything about deploying software in a Windows environment (I'm used to working on linux systems where a simple makefile would suffice)  What tools (preferably command line) are available to compile & organize binaries in a portable way on windows systems?

Comment: AFAIK DevC++ is an IDE, not a compiler.

Comment: Apologies, more specificity I meant MinGW.  What I was getting at was that the current compile & deploy process is that someone compiles all the binaries in the IDE, separately, by hand and then distributes them; so when an update is made the source code it's someone's job to go through every computer in the lab and recompile  each piece in the IDE and replace the binaries with new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you have a C++ compiler usable on the command line, on one translation unit. For example, [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is such a compiler (and [mingw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) is or contains a variant of GCC). Assume also that it is capable of linking (e.g. by driving the system [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing))).

Then you need to use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool to drive such compilation commands. For example [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/) (but there are many others). AFAIK they exist on Windows (so you could port your `Makefile` on Linux to Windows).

Once you have chosen your build automation tool, studied its documentation and understood how to use it, you'll write the relevant configuration file for it. For `make`, you'll write a `Makefile` (caveat : <kbd>tab</kbd> characters are significant). For `ninja`, you'll write some `build.ninja` files (but you'll probably generate it, perhaps with [meson](http://mesonbuild.com/)).

Notice that some build tools (e.g. [cmake](http://cmake.org/)) are cross-platform.

BTW, [DevC++](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.fr/) is an IDE, not a compiler.

Comment: Ninja build files are not designed to be written directly, they are intended to be generated by another build system (such as CMake)

Comment: +1 for CMake. On windows you can use it to generate Visual Studio project files, and I assume the Visual Studio documentation has steps to build via cli.

Comment: Thanks @SeanBurton . I'll take a look at the Cmake documenation; It's been a very long time since I've used it but I think it's probably my best bet.